# Setting UITableView contentInset also insets section header view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm changing my tableviews contentInset, so that when a user scrolls beyond the top bounds of the table, the tableview is inset to display a UISearchBar hidden above the tableView.

Everything works fine apart from the section header views. when scrolling down, the top bound of the sectionHeaderView is inset the same distance from the top of the screen as my tableview inset, here is it in starting position:

[image: Header view in correct position]

In the above image the sectionheader view is set to its correct positon, and the tableview inset has been set to display the search field.

[image]

You can see in this second screenshot where the top bound of the headerview is set lower because of the 43 pixel tableview inset, where as it should stick to the top of the screen hiding the "related" cell and bouncing back when released.

I guess i need to Offset the Inset somehow, i'm just not sure how..

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue (though it's not for hiding a searchbar) and would love to find an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming what you want is a search field like in the Mail application; a search field at the very top of the list that by default is not visible?

The solution is not to use `contentInset`, but instead:

1. Set a `UISearchBar` as the tableviews `tableHeaderView`.
2. Also add a `UISearchDisplayController` to the table view controller.
3. By default set the `contentOffset` to 44 points down, to hide the search bar.

Apple has a good sample app as a starting point here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: That isn't a solution, that's a workaround. There are several cases where you'd want to use contentInset and this causes many problems. To fix this the following is a better solution: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/uitableview-section-header-positions

Comment: @strange You should post a new top-level answer that describes this technique, as it's a valid answer for many people who arrive at this question trying to figure out how to do this.